# Daylight saving and cron Scheduler

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a DAG to run at 00:05 and 12:05 every day. I'm using this crone expression to schedule it "5 12,0 * * *".
my start and end dates are defined as following:

```
TIME_ZONE = "America/Toronto"
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "5 12,0 * * *"
START_DATE = datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=5, hour=0, minute=0, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone(TIME_ZONE))
END_DATE = datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=9, hour=0, minute=0, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone(TIME_ZONE))
```

When running the DAG, I have an extra RUN at 11am on November 7. On that same day daylight saving time is applied in my timezone.

[image] [image]

Is this the expected behaviour ? When trying with "5 12 * * *" the RUNs are scheduled for the same hour regardless of daylight saving time. I want this same behaviour but with two runs in the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was too busy for check that, but try with:

`SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = "5 */12 * * *"`

Comment: Thank you Alejandro for your reply but it's the same behaviour.